# Running a Client-Server program written in Java on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, client

I'm trying to run a client-server program in java on Netbeans.

Here's the code for the server:

```
// File Name GreetingServer.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); #line 48, error arises here. 
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code for the client:

```
// File Name GreetingClient.java

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String serverName = args[0]; #line 10, error arises here 
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

So when I want to simulate the client and the server running together I first run the server.
Once the server is running I need to run the client.

However when I try to run the server file, I get the following error:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at GreetingServer.main(GreetingServer.java:48)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Similarly, when I try to run the client program, I get the following error:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Why is this happening? Please help.

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
    private static int port;
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      port=9000;
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}


// File Name GreetingClient.java

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class GreetingClient
{
    private static String serverName;
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String sName = "MyServerName";
      int port = 9000;
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + sName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(sName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

There is no error on the server side now. But I am still getting the following error on the client side:

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: when tou running your program, are you passing any arguments to it?

Comment: How do you run the server?

Comment: no i'm not. if I should, then where and how do I pass them?

Comment: by right clicking on the .java file and selecting Run

Comment: please have a look at the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code supposes that you pass the port you want to use as an argument so :

- Either you run your application with the line Patryk Roszczyniała posted
- If you don't want to use it, just delete the lines :

  ```
  String serverName = args[0]; 
  int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  ```

  and replace them by hardcoded values like :

  ```
  String serverName = "MyServerName";
  int port = 3000;
  ```

**Update :**

I just tested your code, in fact, the serverName is the address you use to connect to the server, so replace it by `"localhost"` if you are running both client and server on the same machine.

**Tested code :**

Here is the updated code I tested and it should work perfectly if you run both on the same machine.

Client :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class GreetingClient
{
    private static String serverName;
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String sName = "localhost";
      int port = 9000;
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + sName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(sName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Server :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
    private static int port;
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(20000);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      port=9000;
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I compiled and ran your code, I don't get an exception but you ahve to set the serverName at "localhost" to get it to connect.
Check my edit

Comment: I posted you the updated code I tested, check it, it runs perfectly on my computer just by running both of them in Eclipse.

Comment: i copied and pasted your code into Netbeans and it still dosen't work

Comment: I'm getting the same error: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: If you still get an exception, tell me how do you run it now?
If you run it by launching a .jar, make sure you regenerated the executable.jar after making the corrections.

Comment: could this have anything to do with not setting the classpath variable?

Comment: I don't know how it is possible, I tested it in NetBeans too, I just copy-pasted my code in two Java classes, right clicked on the GreetingServer.java and pressed run file and I did the same thing with GreetingClient.java and it works perfectly.

Comment: i'm right clicking on the .java file in the netbeans IDE and clicking on run

Comment: I don't understand, you can't get an error on something you don't use. Make sure you edited the right file and you are running the same .java you edited.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing too =/

Comment: I reinstalled Netbeans, deleted all the existing projects and ran the code again. Now it's fine :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To run `SocketServer` you need to pass port on which server will work. For example:

```
SocketServer server = new SocketServer(1234);
```

The problem is that you want to pass port by java argument and you aren't doing that. First of all before use of any variable you should first validate it.

```
if (args.length>0) {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); #line 48, error arises here. 
}
```

Your program requires params but I think that you probably run your program without params.
You should run program in this way: `java -jar app.jar 1234`
But you do it in this way: `java -jar app.jar`

In this article you will find how to pass parameters to java program using netbeans http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html.

If you are new in java you should first read this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/. It's very helpful.

Comment: You've got the same problem with client. You try to pass `arg[0]` as port but `arg` array is empty. You should validate arg array before use it and pass port for client using command line or just hardcode port for client.

Comment: have another look, I've hardcoded the port number. It's now: String sName = "MyServerName"; int port = 9000;

Comment: And you've got still exception?

Comment: moreover why am I still getting the array index out of bounds as an exception when I am no longer using args[]?

Comment: I think that you should read this article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ first.

Comment: could this have anything to do with not setting the classpath variable?

Comment: What exception have you got now? Still ArrayIndexOutOfBound?

Comment: I reinstalled Netbeans, deleted all the existing projects and ran the code again. Now it's fine :)